# Angular Js : Using ng-if I need to change the status in real time from active to inactive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my view i am using angular ng-repeat

```
tr(data-ng-repeat="admin in admins")
                  td {{$index+1}}
                  td {{admin.profile.AdminName}}
                  td(ng-if = "admin.account.status === 1") active
                  td(ng-if = "admin.account.status === 0") Inactive
```

Now in my controllers I make a REST call and get the status value changed , but it appears only after page reload I need to change the message when changed from active to inactive to be shown in real time not on reload. .
I  am doing something like this

```
    $http.post("/admin/changeAdminStatus/" + $scope.value)
    .success(function(){
$scope.admin.account.status = !$scope.admin.account.status;
```

but it does not help what can be the possibe way to do the changes.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.admin doesnt exist on scope as its part of your ng-repeat scope (when it iterates).

You will need to change the original value in 'admins' e.g. $scope.admins[0].account.status = 1;

Comment: I have a button called change status with ng-click inside this ng-repeat where I pass the id and get my status changed on click of that button, and thus the changes are not reflecting, also the status will either be 0 or be 1 ,

Comment: show more code, at least the function and the button that execute the status change.